# Why I can't get hasOwnProperty from constructor directly?

Tags: javascript, object, oop, constructor, prototype

I am puzzled by the impossibility of direct access to the **OWN** constructor properties meanwhile there is access to prototype props **THAT ARE NOT OWN** properties

```js
function Friend(){
  this.said = function(){
    return 'Hey, bro!'
  }
}

patrick = new Friend();

//true
true === patrick.hasOwnProperty('said')

//false? why?
true === Friend.hasOwnProperty('said')

//meanwhile I can access to prototype props THAT ARE NOT OWN properties
Friend.prototype.donald = "Hi! I am not own property! I am prototype prop.";

//true
false === Friend.hasOwnProperty('donald')

//"Hi! I am not own property! I am prototype prop."
new Friend().donald

//"Hey, bro!"
new Friend().said()
```

Comment: "*//false? why?*" because it's not an own property? The name of the method `hasOwnProperty()` should be descriptive enough, I thought. Moreover, `said` doesn't even exist anywhere on `Friend`. It's just attached to instances of it.

Comment: @VLAZ why then copies of Friend got this as own property?

Comment: They aren't *copies*. They are *instances*. And they get the own property because it's directly attached to each instance in the body of the constructor. If you had `f = obj => { obj.foo = 42; }` that also attaches a direct own property to any object passed in. So with `o = {}; f(o);` you get an own property on `o`. But that property is not at all related to fields on the function `f`. Same with `Friend` - `said` is not something defined *on* `Friend` anywhere. As you see because at no point you define it on `Friend`. There is no code like `Friend.said = "something"` or anywhere like that.

Comment: "*Why `Friend.hasOwnProperty('said')` is false?*" - because there is no `Friend.said` property on the `Friend` (function) object!

Comment: @VLAZ how about `new Friend().said() === "Hey, bro!"`? I didn't transfer any object into it. Where from I inherit `said` then?

Comment: @PDD It didn't *inherit* `said`. Again - the property is *directly attached* in the constructor body itself. Same as how the `f` function directly attaches `foo`. The line `this.said = "whatever"` attaches a property on the object. You can also do the same outside the constructor with `patrick.yelled = () => console.log("HEY, BRO!");`. The property is still not inherited. It's added on the object itself. Exactly the same way `said` is, just at different time.

Comment: Okay @VLAZ how I can select your answer as solution?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to `true === Friend.hasOwnProperty('said')`

Because `Friend` is function, and `Friend.__proto__` will point to `Function.prototype`.
meanwhile `patrick.__proto__` will point to `Friend.prototype`

This might be helpful for you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

Comment: "*meanwhile patrick.__proto__ will point to Friend.prototype*" that's not really relevant - `said` doesn't come from the prototype. If it did, it wouldn't be an *own* property.